# JavaScript function access to object property

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code return just an empty string:

```
var a = {
     name:"321",
     foo: function(){
        console.log(name);
    }
}

a.foo();
```

Comment: `console.log(this.name);`

Comment: Check the browser's console. It should print nothing. Change `name` to `this.name` and you should see `321` printed!

Comment: @Noah, actually it will print something. Empty string! See [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Comment: Good catch @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because you haven't scoped name to anything so it's looking for a global variable.
try replacing

```
console.log(name);
```

with

```
console.log(this.name);
```

Comment: I understand that 'this.name' works. I just wonder why function hasn't access to 'name' property.

Comment: @user2598794 Because without `this`, the code will search a scoped variable named `name`, and another property of the same object isn t considered inside the scope. If you had a global var `name`, you would see it value.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Why 'name' in the object isn't considered inside the scope? And where it starts the search?

Comment: @user2598794 In your example, it start inside `a.foo`, then continue in the global code. I don't know the reason JS act like that though.

Comment: JS is built on functions and their closures. The associated object can easily change, and a single function could be in multiple objects.

Comment: @user2598794: I have posted a answer to provide you a example of how JS engine search the scope.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `this` keyword like this - `console.log(this.name);` .In result of your code, you see an empty string and not a undefined error because `window.name` variable already exists and has nothing to do with the name variable in your object

Answer (score 1):

Following comments on Rich Linnell answer:

foo is for the object's function scope exemple, and bar for callbacks's scopes.

Code:

```
var foo = "global",
    bar = "global",
    a = {
    foo: (callback) => {
        // var foo = 'local';
        console.log('foo: ' + foo);
        callback();
    }
};

(() => {
    // var bar = "parent";
    a.foo(() => {
        // var bar = "local";
        console.log('bar: ' + bar);
    });
})();
```

Comment: I commented out only the '1' name and it prints me "name: 3". And if I commented '1' and '3' it prints empty string. Looks like it doesn't see function scope at all.

Comment: @user2598794: Ah, yes, I forgot that in that case it skip to the global scope, unlike callbacks. I ve edited my example.